# SSRS report inconsistently showing rows

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have a report where the query in SSMS is showing data correctly. However, when it comes to displaying it in SSRS, rows are slipping between the cracks for some reason. In this case, a row with the DetailChargeItem of "Special Vehicle Install".

In the past, recreating the report has resolved the issue and I did so because it was a simple layout. However, this report is a bit more complicated, so I'd like to instead find out what the problem is so I can address it.

Here's my data example from SSMS, so I know the data is actually there:

| ServiceDate | First_Name | DetailChargeItem | AmountService |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Nov 30 2021 | Ryan | Install | 115.00 |
| Nov 30 2021 | Ryan | Scheduled Service | 25.00 |
| Nov 30 2021 | Ryan | Special Vehicle Install | 99.00 |

However only these two charges are showing:

[image]

Strangely enough, on the same page just above that example, there is this example below that has the same charges, but deciding to show the charge that is missing on the first example (Special Vehicle Install).

[image]

Now I do have row groups, but there are no special exceptions anywhere. The grouping that affects the correctly-shown example also affects the incorrectly-shown example. No filters in the report's construction either. I've looked at the report's properties, and under General, the CanGrow property is set to True (this is as close as I could find to a potential explanation). Also, no parameters that could affect this (only start and end date). I'm hoping this is an issue that someone has encountered and knows more about.

Comment: Have you tried the "KeepTogether" flag on the row group properties?

Comment: You brilliant man, you. That was the ticket, thank you! Didn't know about this property lol